# How do I search the contents of an email in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How do I search the contents of an email in Outlook? I've tried `Ctrl-f`, right clicking and it didn't work. I also searched online but don't see anyone asking this exact question.

Comment: low tech way would be to use the search box in Outlook - by default it looks at e-mail content

Comment: check this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-a-message-or-item-with-instant-search-69748862-5976-47b9-98e8-ed179f1b9e4d

Comment: @mael' it searches for the email containing the text, but doesn't locate the search term.

Comment: @Perry why? I didn't see anything interesting there.

Comment: it should also locate contents - make sure your indexing is turned on - especially if it’s not in your primary mailbox

Comment: @PhilipRego  I misunderstand your requirement before. Search in contents of an email, we may try Advanced find: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3625-outlook-search-in-email-body.html

Comment: @Perry thank you it worked. F4 is the shortcut

Comment: Fun fact, pressing Ctrl-F begins the process of Forwarding the message. If you click to put the cursor into the new email, you can then press Ctrl-F again to bring up the search dialog. This was suggested to me as a workaround for this issue by a coworker. I can't help but wonder how many other microsoft users are miserably following this sort of process because it gets them where they need to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's <kbd>F4</kbd>. [More Outlook keyboard shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-3cdeb221-7ae5-4c1d-8c1d-9e63216c1efd).

Comment: unbelievable....who does that...